# How do I properly test whether my Port Forwarding works?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, wireless-networking

I have set up a website in iis which runs on port 5000

Now when I type 192.168.2.2:5000 I get that page.

Now, I do port forwarding with my Belkin Router using http://screenshots.portforward.com/Belkin/F7D2301v1/Virtual_Servers.htm

Now, I find my IP using http://whatismyip.com and I found it to be 117.x.x.x

Now, in my browser when I type 117.x.x.x:5000, fiddler throws me this message

```
[Fiddler] Connection to 117.x.x.x failed.
Exception Text: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond 117.x.x.x:5000
```

Answer (score 7):

Try accessing your web server from *outside* your network. Many (most?) routers ship without "routeback" (possibly a vendor-specific term, I'm not sure, sorry) enabled, if they even support it, which is necessary for routing an internal connection attempt back into the internal network.

I have yet to see an off-the-shelf consumer-grade router with an option to enable this feature.

So what does this mean to you? It means that from within your network, you *must* use your server's internal IP (192.168.2.2); from *outside* your network, you *must* use your router's external IP (117.x.x.x).

A quick-and-easy check can be made using the [Open Port Check Tool](http://canyouseeme.org/), although this only tells you if the connection on port 5000 is being *accepted*, not that it is correctly serving you web site. For that, you can try the [HTTP/HTTPS Header Check](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php); if it gets a valid response, you're in business!

Comment: What you're describing is also known as a U-Turn NAT.

Comment: @Kromey every (consumer) router I've owned's worked fine...

Comment: @Tom The IETF refers to this as "hairpin NAT" or "NAT hairpinning" in the RFCs/BCPs ([RFC 5382 (BCP 142)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5382), [RFC 4787 (BCP 127)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4787)).

Comment: @Michael Every consumer router I've owned has not supported/not enabled this feature -- sure, it technically works fine, but it can't/doesn't do "hairpin NAT". These days, though, I use low-end PC hardware running Linux, with Shorewall, where enabling this feature is as easy as turning on the "routeback" option for the internal interface.

Comment: Yeah, most if not all consumer routers do not support hairpins.

Comment: @Kromey what are the symptoms of no support for hairpins? A traceroute to my router's public IP has one hop, the router, and all hosted services forward correctly and are accessible from the private LAN using external or internal IPs

Comment: @Michael Really the only symptom is that trying to access port forwarded services from the internal network via the router's external IP simply fails to get forwarded to the internal server. I'm sure there are some consumer devices that do support it (there's no reason I can think of not to), and it sounds like yours is one of them.